How to seekg on a gz file
I'm working on a gzip file reader to handle huge .gz files.
I want to split a file into multiple chunks, and record the start position of each chunk, then the chunked data can be processed parallelly.
However, getline always fails after seekg.
Is it possible to seekg on a gzip file?
My code is like:
int main() {
    // Open the gzipped file
    std::ifstream file("my.gz", std::ios::binary);

    // Create a filtering stream for decompression
    boost::iostreams::filtering_stream<boost::iostreams::input> decompressedStream;
    decompressedStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    decompressedStream.push(file);

    // Read the first line
    std::string line;
    std::cout << "firstLineStartPos: " << file.tellg() << std::endl;
    std::getline(decompressedStream, line);
    std::cout << "First line: " << line << std::endl;

    // Record the start position of the second line
    std::streampos secondLineStartPos = file.tellg();
    std::cout << "secondLineStartPos: " << secondLineStartPos << std::endl;

    // Read the second line
    std::getline(decompressedStream, line);
    std::cout << "Second line: " << line << std::endl;

    // Jump back to the start position of the second line
    file.clear();  // Clear any error flags in the file stream
    file.seekg(secondLineStartPos);

    // Recreate the decompression stream
    decompressedStream.reset();  // Clear the existing data from the filtering stream
    decompressedStream.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    decompressedStream.push(file);

    // Read the second line again
    std::getline(decompressedStream, line);
    std::cout << "Second line (again): " << line << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

And, the output is like:
firstLineStartPos: 0
First line: # item1 item2 item3 item4 item5 item6
secondLineStartPos: 8192
Second line: Bump_0 uBump_1 0.00000 0.00000 VDD1 VDD1
Second line (again): 

The getline fails after seekg?

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor() is not stateless. So when you seek input stream state of boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor() is wrong to decode file at new place. Note most compression algorithms are building some kind of dictionary and update it as data are compressed or decompressed. So to come back to some place inn compressed file you would have to restore state of decompressor. I do not thing it is possible (or simple and safe).

That code is a big no-go: either access the file, or access the decompressedStream -- don't try to mix these two. The second you use the decompressedStream, that object basically owns your file.

Observation: You're using Boost so that you don't need to know the details of how compression works. Then you get a position within the compressed file as if you know how compression works (and that it stores data sequentially). Notice the inconsistency? This is a big warning flag. (ex: In theory, a compression algorithm could have a way of encoding "word 1 from the dictionary occurs three times with separators; separator 1 is words 4 through 8 of the dictionary; separator 2 is a new line". There is no word 1 after the new line in the compressed file, but there is one in the decompressed.).

I would expect once decompressStream gets file, then that's it.  You should not be getting into the seekg and tellg business at all after that, as you are messing around with the internals without knowing what the internals are.
